# Why does python append 0000 to every UTF-32 encoded character?

Tags: python, unicode

Try:

```
codecs.getencoder('hex_codecs')(codecs.getencoder('utf-32')('a')[0])
```

Python will output:

```
('fffe000061000000', 8)
```

Why python append 0000 to the UTF-32 encoded string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just ordering the bytes in opposite (little-endian) order than you may expect. The same in PHP:

```
> bin2hex(iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-32', 'a'));
0000feff00000061
```

`0000feff` is the UTF-32 BOM, `00000061` is "a".

`UTF-32` [defaults to "natural endianness"](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode). If you want something specific, use `UTF-32-BE` or `UTF-32-LE`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't. `61000000` is the (little-endian) UTF-32 encoding of U+0061, LATIN SMALL LETTER A. `6100` would be the (little-endian) UTF-16 encoding, and `61` would be the UTF-8 encoding.